# oracle form many records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I need that return all the records of the table in the master detail, for that i use trigger WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM and i 'm using this code

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR N IS 
          SELECT B.CODIGO_BARRA, B.REFER, B.DESC_PROD, B.CANT, B.PRECIO
          FROM PS62 B
          WHERE B.NRODOCTO = :E.NRO_DOCTO_PEDIDO
          AND B.CODCIA = :E.CODCIA;

BEGIN 
      GO_BLOCK('D');
      FIRST_RECORD;
             FOR I IN N  LOOP
                      :D.CODIGO_BARRA := I.CODIGO_BARRA;
                      :D.REFER := I.REFER;
                      :D.DESC_PROD := I.DESC_PROD;
                      :D.CANT := I.CANT;
                      :D.COSTO := I.PRECIO;
        NEXT_RECORD;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

this just only returns me one records. please help me!

Comment: You do not need any triggers to create master-detail, this is totally wrong. You need to create relation. Use forms wizard to create master-detail form. It will guide you through.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly not a way to populate a data block in Oracle Forms. Even if you manage to do that, Forms will consider those rows *new* and - if you attempt to save them - you'll get the primary/unique key violation.

You should have used the Data Block Wizard which guides you through a process of creating a master block (which is usually in a form layout, displaying a single record).

Then run the Wizard again in order to create the detail block (which is usually displayed in a tabular layout, showing several records). Make sure to create the relationship between those two blocks.

If those tables are properly created (i.e. have primary keys as well as a foreign key that establishes the master-detail relationship), Forms will automatically offer which columns should be joined.

Once the Wizard is done, that form will be functional in all ways - you don't have to write a single line of code. So, you can

- query those tables

  - querying master will retrieve its details **automatically**, without any loops written in your own program unit
- enter new values,
- update or delete existing ones.

---

As of code you wrote: Barbaros told you how to fix it, but it won't work anyway in the `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger as you can't use restricted procedures (such as `GO_BLOCK` or `FIRST_RECORD`) in it. It really doesn't matter, as the way you'd want to do it is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a `COMMIT` to return the records.

The Target Block always should be cleared( `CLEAR_BLOCK(NO_VALIDATE)` needed for this aim to be performed without any pop-up),

and by using `FIRST_RECORD` again, take your cursor to the top of the records at the end of returning all.

So, you may use the following :

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR N IS 
          SELECT B.CODIGO_BARRA, B.REFER, B.DESC_PROD, B.CANT, B.PRECIO
          FROM PS62 B
          WHERE B.NRODOCTO = :E.NRO_DOCTO_PEDIDO
          AND B.CODCIA = :E.CODCIA;

BEGIN 
      GO_BLOCK('D');
      CLEAR_BLOCK(NO_VALIDATE);
      FIRST_RECORD;
             FOR I IN N  LOOP
                      :D.CODIGO_BARRA := I.CODIGO_BARRA;
                      :D.REFER := I.REFER;
                      :D.DESC_PROD := I.DESC_PROD;
                      :D.CANT := I.CANT;
                      :D.COSTO := I.PRECIO;
        NEXT_RECORD;
    END LOOP;
   FIRST_RECORD;
END;
```